# How to plot combo plot in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

my data frame i am using is
[image: the dataframe i am using]

the output I'm trying to achieve
[image: desired output]
I achieved this output in excel and I'm trying to reproduce it in R but I am not able to get the 2 lines
I tried using the code

```
ggplot(yearly_percentage) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=year, y=count_percentage, fill=member_casual), position = "dodge",stat = "identity") +
  geom_line( aes(x=year,y=ride_Length))
```

[image]
this is the output I get

here is my reproduceable sample of data frame

```
structure(list(year = c("2016", "2016", "2017", "2017", "2018", 
"2018", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020"), member_casual = c("casual", 
"member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", 
"casual", "member"), count_percentage = c("23.88%", "76.12%", 
"21.86%", "78.14%", "18.79%", "81.21%", "23.06%", "76.94%", "11.31%", 
"88.69%"), ride_Length = c("45%", "55%", "42%", "58%", "46.6%", 
"53.4%", "51.5%", "48.5%", "42%", "58%")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message suggest you have to set the `group` aes and as you probably want colored lines you have to map on the `color` aes additionally. Also note, that your columns are not numerics but characters. Hence you have to convert them to numerics and instead format as percentages via the `labels` argument of `scale_y_continuous`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

yearly_percentage$count_percentage <- readr::parse_number(yearly_percentage$count_percentage)
yearly_percentage$ride_Length <- readr::parse_number(yearly_percentage$ride_Length)

ggplot(yearly_percentage) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = year, y = count_percentage, fill = member_casual), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = ride_Length, color = member_casual, group = member_casual)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(scale = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I understood where I was making mistakes.